# uicollectionview cell position not aligned on grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using a uicollectionview to populate a grid (4x5 cells).Now, sometimes, but not always, I am getting 2 cells that are not aligned with the grid, but they are ~1/4 of the cell size off to the left or right. It appears consistently but not every time the grid is populated.

Has anyone seen this happening before? Any tips on how to identify the cause would be helpful.

[image: cell moved outside the grid]

Comment: Best solution  is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956954/ios-horizontally-scrolling-collectionview-with-images/42957646#42957646

Answer (score 0):

try to implement

```
    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat cellSize =  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/4;

    return CGSizeMake(cellSize, cellSize);
}
```

and setting your collection view layout:

```
 -(void)setCollectionViewLayout {

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2;
    flow.minimumLineSpacing = 2;

    [yourCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flow];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to locate a similar error post that resolved the situation for me.

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
then:

[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19100840/7753681